How to set script prerequisites
A while ago I created a small Use-ClassAccessors script and uploaded that to the PowerShell Gallery.
Now I am creating another script that has a dependency on the Use-ClassAccessors script.
Is there something like a #Requires directive or Using statement where I can set this prerequisite in my new script similar to what might be done for modules?
(btw. the Using statement appears to have an undocumented command usingstatementkind  but I no clue what the syntax is).

You already know the answer, re-upload it as a Module instead of Script and add the requirements to the RequiredModules / RequiredAssemblies etc.

@SantiagoSquarzon, I just want to confirm as (gallery) scripts  are lighter and easier to maintain than modules. Besides, if that is indeed the only answer, I am considering to do a formal a Feature Request / Idea for this.

‍♂️ if not a Module then isn't it something you can validate via if statement and throw when requirements not met?
